# Stuck at splash with "Waiting for network configuration"

Tags: boot, networking

I just restarted my Elementary OS and it is stuck at splash screen with a text

```
Waiting for network configuration...
```

Comment: Nope, I opened my computer and installed Divinity Origin Sin on Steam. However, since my gpu is amd and offical drivers don't suppport OpenGL 4, I change my gpu drivers from Additional Drivers (something like that from Software Manager) but steam is kind of went into deadlock so I restarted my pc, and this is like that since.

Comment: Are you able to login to system? The problem appear on every login? If no GUI available can you login via `Ctrl+Alt+F1` ?

Comment: Nope, at this screen it doesn't login or comes to a login screen. It's like this:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UEjn9WlvJdo/UmJconk7eoI/AAAAAAAAavA/3X6ey1-Hvu4/s1600/Screenshot+from+2013-10-19+12:17:10.png
But has a text at the bottom of logo as "Waiting for network configuration".

Also it doesn't answer to 'Ctrl+Alt+F1', I didn't try anything from GRUB since I don't have knowledge on it.

Comment: I have posted my answer, press Ctrl + Alt + F1 if not working change to F2. like you can use upto F6.

Comment: No, it doesn't response to any terminal commands from F1 to F6. It doesn't response to anything so I always have to restart PC from power button.